# Recode values to be able and match different DF in R

Tags: r

I have a very odd problem that I cant make out.

I have this DF

```
> close
               V1                   V2   V3
1     Gunnilse IS          IK Gauthiod  3.1
2   IFK Uddevalla            IFK Kumla 1.33
3  LidkÃ¶pings FK       Grebbestads IF 3.25
4   Skoftebyns IF         Kortedala IF 1.85
5     SkÃ¶vde AIK          Rynninge IK 1.45
6 Stenungsunds IF          Karlstad BK  5.5
7 VÃ¤nersborgs FK Ã–rebro Syrianska IF  2.1
```

Now I have to recode values in V1 and V2 to able and match data from another DF. I am using package car to recode values.

```
close$V1 <- recode(close$V1,"'LidkÃ¶pings FK'='Lidköpings FK' ;'SkÃ¶vde AIK' = 'Skövde AIK';'Ã–rebro Syrianska IF' = 'Örebro Syrianska IF';'VÃ¤nersborgs FK'='Vänersborgs FK'")
close$V2 <- recode(close$V2,"'LidkÃ¶pings FK'='Lidköpings FK' ;'SkÃ¶vde AIK' = 'Skövde AIK';'Ã–rebro Syrianska IF' = 'Örebro Syrianska IF';'VÃ¤nersborgs FK'='Vänersborgs FK'")
```

This works fine for all value expect 'Ã–rebro Syrianska IF'. Following test results in FALSE.

```
> "Ã–rebro Syrianska IF" == close[7,2]
[1] FALSE
```

Test will result in TRUE for all other values in close$V1 and close$V2 and I have followed same procedure, simply copy and paste values that I have to recode in to line with recoding.

What could cause this and is there any way around my problem? I guess one option could be to recode values in other DF, but those are more and would imply more work.

Comment: where you from? what's that language?

Comment: @MattBannert, I guess it's Swedish

Comment: Ok assuming @docendo discimus is right, latin1 should work. Try to set encoding="latin1" when reading the data. Assuming your input file is xlsx and encoded that way. A utf-8 text file would be better though. Lots of assumptions here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have got an encoding problem. Can you run `Sys.getlocale()`. Where do you get your data from? `csv`? `xlsx` ? Read functions have encoding parameters. Get your characters right when you are comparing based on characters. That being said, you would also want to set the infamous `stringsAsFactors` to FALSE. If you provide further reproducible details I might be able edit my answer and give a more concrete fix.

Comment: Not sure what got it right, but I added both stringsAsFactors to FALSE and encoded data to "latin1".

Thanks for all your help :)